# Problems with using PlaySound in C++ with VS Code

Tags: visual-c++

I have been seeing people adding winmm library to linkers in other Code editors which doesn't exist in VS Code. For that I only found #pragma.
However even after that I keep getting errors.
I would also like to know how can I get Solutions Explorer in VS Code, I have seen the thing on a Video using which the guy mad things work.
This is the Video -:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOljIjBJvRI&ab_channel=MaxO%27Didily

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<mmsystem.h>
#include<string>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Playing Music -:" << endl;
    PlaySound(TEXT("G:\\GitHub\\OSDHACK-23\\Pyar Hua Iqrar Hua.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);

    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    PlaySound(0,0,0);
    cout << "Stopped Music" << endl;

    getline(cin, input);
    cout << "Playing Music" << endl;
    PlaySound(TEXT("G:\\GitHub\\OSDHACK-23\\Pyar Hua Iqrar Hua.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);

    getline(cin, input);
    return 0;
}
```

This has been my code till now but I keep getting this error -:
C:\Users\avira\AppData\Local\Temp\ccccj9eC.o:sound.cpp:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Would like some help on the same.

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")` will only work if you are using the Microsoft compiler. If you are using `gcc` you will need to supply the library on the compile/link command line.